# How 0x01010101 is equivalent to 1<<24 + 1<<16 + 1<<8 + 1

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, swar

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081738/how-does-this-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer-work/22084043#22084043) question gives explanation about [SWAR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR) used for counting number of 1s in a given number. While explaining [ilmari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411022/ilmari-karonen) wrote 
**0x01010101 = (1 << 24) + (1 << 16) + (1 << 8) + 1**. Can someone explain how it is equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll first need to understand what the `<<` operator is doing. It performs a bitwise shift to the left. Let's adopt the `0b` prefix for binary notation and `0x` for hexadecimal notation:

```
1 << 8 = 0b100000000 = 256 = 0x100
```

Similarly:

```
1 << 16 = 0b10000000000000000 = 65536 = 0x10000
```

So:

```
(1 << 8) + (1 << 16) = 0x10100
```

By adding `(1 << 24)` and `1`, you'll get the final result: `0x01010101`.

Please note that while it looks an awful lot like a binary value, it is a hexadecimal one. If we write it as binary, we get:

```
 0b1000000010000000100000001
   ^       ^       ^       ^
bit #24 bit #16  bit #8  bit #0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  Shifting 1 left by 24 places
          1 0000 0000 0000 0000  Shifting 1 left by 16 places
                    1 0000 0000  Shifting 1 left by  8 places
                              1  
================================
1 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001   Result after adding
```

I.e. 0x01010101.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the total number:

```
Hex:     0x01010101
Decimal: 16843009
Binary:  1000000010000000100000001
```

Now look at them individually. Start with `1 << 24` (aka. 1 [left shifted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift) 24 times, aka. a binary 1 with 24 zeroes):

```
Calculation: 1 << 24
Decimal: 16777216
Binary: 1000000000000000000000000
//      ^ 25th position because 1 was shifted 24 times to the left

Calculation: 1 << 16
Decimal: 65536
Binary: 0000000010000000000000000
//              ^ 17th position because 1 was shifted 16 times to the left

Calculation: 1 << 8
Decimal: 256
Binary: 0000000000000000100000000
//                      ^ 9th position because 1 was shifted 8 times to the left
```

1 is obvious, so I won't include that. Now add them all together:

```
  1000000000000000000000000 = 1 << 24
  0000000010000000000000000 = 1 << 16
  0000000000000000100000000 = 1 << 8
+ 0000000000000000000000001 = 1
  |-------|-------|-------|
  1000000010000000100000001 = 16843009
```

And then we're back at the start, `16843009` in hex is `0x01010101`.